# expressJS/Node app running error

Tags: node.js, express

I use expressJs and today i got errors . i reinstall node.js and expressJs but my problem is not solve . when i use and run auto-generating express app or when run my other app i got errors like this .

localserver error

```
 500 Error: C:\express-app\test\test\views\layout.jade:1<br/> > 1| doctype 5 <br/> 2| html <br/> 3| head <br/> 4| title= title <br/><br/>`doctype 5` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype html`
```

screenShots CMD

[image]

Comment: Can you put your layout.jade code ?

Comment: @FÔx Gênki this code auto generating by express
`doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content`

Comment: @H.T The error output gives you the solution. Use `doctype html` rather than `doctype 5`. The latter isn't supported (being `deprecated`) by the version of `jade` that you have installed.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski i change it but i have problem . **the above code auto generating by express command**

Comment: @H.T It was probably generating for an `0.x` version of `jade`. But, since you have `1.x` installed, the line is no longer valid. Also note that Express [won't be including the command](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/476f8deb07d48aac146a94262ea65b7991d840be) going forward.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, as you say my problem was solve . tanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says how to resolve it:

```
`doctype 5` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype html`
```

Just change the `5` to `html` at the start of `_layout.jade`:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
# ...
```

This was one of quite a few changes made with the [release of `jade@1.0.0`](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/History.md#100--2013-12-22):

> - Remove `5` shorcut for `html` doctype (@ForbesLindesay)

Comment: that's true, @H.T : look at this issue too : https://github.com/visionmedia/express/pull/1875

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski tanks a lot